# How to load source data in GroupDataModel for ListView in Blackberry 10 cascade?

Tags: xml, listview, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades, datamodel

Here is my line of code where I want to load `source:` data from xml file which is located in my device shared folder.

The path of that xml file is `QFile textfile("/accounts/1000/shared/documents/myData.xml");`

My code is:

```
import bb.cascades 1.0
import bb.data 1.0
Page {
content: ListView {
id: listView
dataModel: dataModel
    ...
}
attachedObjects: [
    GroupDataModel {
    id: dataModel
    },
        DataSource {
      id: dataSource


     //---------------------------------------
     //Here I want to load xml file
     //---------------------------------------
      source: "/accounts/1000/shared/documents/myData.xml"
    //---------------------------------------


      query: "/contacts/contact"
      onDataLoaded: {
        dataModel.insertList(data);
      }
    }
  ]
  onCreationCompleted: { dataSource.load(); }
}
```

Anyone please help me, how exactly load xml file in GroupDataModel which is located in above device directory location.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have two parts to do this :

First  one allowing your application to use shared folders

Steps:

1. Go to bar-descriptor.xml in your project
2. select Application
3. check true in shared files

Second one is Get the correct path using C++ and send it to Qml in context property

This in your ApllicationUI.cpp
 C++ Code

```
// Build the path, add it as a context property, and expose
// it to QML
QString workingDir = QDir::currentPath();
QString path = "file://" + workingDir +"/shared/documents/model.xml";
QDeclarativePropertyMap* dirPaths = new QDeclarativePropertyMap;
dirPaths->insert("documents", QVariant(QString(path)));
qml->setContextProperty("dirPaths", dirPaths);
```

QML

```
    dataModel: XmlDataModel {
            source: dirPaths.documents
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[image: Snapshot to explore bar-descriptor.xml]

this snapshot describe how to reach permissions->shared files